# Retrieve Form data from Service in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a structure like this:
FATHER component with a stepper
On each step-page i have a CHILD component with a FORM
In one page, CHILD have another CHILD with another FORM.

On the last page of stepper i have the SUBMIT. On Submit i must retrieve and compose all the data of form.

What's the bestway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Openion the best practice is to user **@output** and **EventEmitter**. you can take a look at this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular) if you want a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a store (NgRx). You can provide an Action like "storeDataFromStepX" for each of the steps. In the final component you can select all the stored data.

Comment: Finally in the project we decided to use Service. How i can get data form a form with a service?

Comment: You can use within component.

get data(): YourDataObject {
  return this.yourService.data;
}
 Then treat data as a component member.